# Issue creating AVD on command prompt in windows XP

Tags: android, eclipse, command-prompt, android-virtual-device

I am the beginner for android development. I followed the procedure as specified in developer.google.com . for installing I Tried to create AVD(Android virtual device) through command path. I executed at command prompt.

```
 android create avd --target 2 --name my_avd
```

But the Error is coming "`Error: Target id is not valid. Use 'android.bat list targets' to get the target ids`."

After executing `android.bat` list targets is showing blank. I am not able to figure out the problem as I have already set the path also.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the full command line string you're using?

Answer (score 2):

THe problem is resolved. windows by default is not loading api for android virtual device. we need to manually start the downloading of those. follow this procedure:

1. go to android List item sdk folder which u have extracted. to the tools folder
2. un android batch file a api would be loaded. Here go to settings and mark "Force https to fetch from http".
3. Then go to availabe packages and amrk the link provided and install it.

   after following this procedure all the above specified errors would be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use "android create avd -n xxx -t 2" to create AVD, and use "android.bat list targets" to find the creation result.
You should use "android list avds" to list AVD. Targets is different from virtual devices.

Comment: THe problem is resolved.

windows by default is not loading api for android virtual device.
we need to manually start the downloading of those.
follow this procedure:
-> go to android sdk folder which u have extracted. to the tools folder
-> Run android batch file a api would be loaded. Here go to settings and mark "Force https to fetch from http
-> Then go to availabe packages and amrk the link provided and install it.

after following this procedure all the above specified errors would be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You may have no targets installed. Check available packages in sdk manager and install some.

Answer (score 0):

As per dtmilano, install some packages [images of the different Android OS versions]. This is an easy step to miss.

FYI: here are the end-to-end steps for installing an app on the emulator using the cmd line tools on MacOS (I assume win64 is equivalent):
http://richardboardman.com/2011/07/100-days-of-tech-day-1-android-dev-tools/